Usando la gema searchkick no trae ningun resultado
En el gemfile tengo:
gem "elasticsearch"

gem "searchkick", "~> 5.2"

En el modelo Book tengo:
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick word_start: [:genre]

  def search_data
    {
      genre: genre
    }
  end

end

Estos son los registros de prueba:
rb(main):040> Book.all.select(:id, :genre)
  Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "books"."id", "books"."genre" FROM "books" /* loading for pp */ LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> 
[#<Book:0x0000558998e56920 id: 1, genre: "genero 1">,
 #<Book:0x0000558998e56858 id: 2, genre: "terror">,
 #<Book:0x0000558998e56768 id: 3, genre: "drama">,
 #<Book:0x0000558998e566a0 id: 4, genre: "genero 4">]

Ejecuto el reindex para asegurarme que searchkick tenga los últimos cambios:
Book.reindex

Hago la busqueda con searchkick de todo con asteristo "*" y me trae todos los 4 registros:
irb(main):045> bb = Book.search "*"
  Book Search (14.1ms)  books_development/_search {"query":{"match_all":{}},"timeout":"11000ms","_source":false,"size":10000}
  Book Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" IN (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2], ["id", 3], ["id", 4]]
=> #<Searchkick::Relation [#<Book id: 1, title: "titulo", author: "autor", genre: "genero 1", price: 0.1234e3, created_at: "2024-10-1...
irb(main):046> bb.size
=> 4

El problema se presenta cuando trato de hacer una busqueda parcial de palabras que empiezan con "dra" y no trae nada:
irb(main):052> bb = Book.search "dra"
  Book Search (51.1ms)  books_development/_search {"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"multi_match":{"query":"dra","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"dra","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"dra","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"dra","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}}]}}]}},"timeout":"11000ms","_source":false,"size":10000}
=> #<Searchkick::Relation []>
irb(main):048> bb.size
=> 0

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?
¿Que me falta?

Siglos que no ocupo searchkick, pero podrías probar depurando las consultas y ver que es lo que te entrega o no
